# MS Access: Auto-populate form fields based on multiple tables

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, populate

I have the following 3 tables:
Retailers - ID, Name
Registration - ID, Status (YES/NO)
Refund - ID (populated into a dropdown list from Retailers table), Name (Empty), Status (Empty)

Retailers is a table full of data, while Refund starts off as an empty table that gets filled in as a Refund Form is filled up. After creating a form based on the Refund table, how do I allow a user to select an ID from the dropdown list and populate the corresponding Name into the Name field and Status into the Status field?

What are the queries needed and how do I integrate this into the form?

I have tried the method found  here - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/autofill-form-microsoft-access-tim-miles

However, I have run into 2 problems:

1) The form does not appear in "Form View"; it is only viewable in layout view. I have read many links saying that the queries are read-only or that there are no records in the first place etc. The answers don't make sense.

2) If I bind the form (instead of a table) to a query this way, how do I save this new data into another table? My intention was to have the record saved in Refund table.

Comment: We need more details to help, which field you complete in your Refund form ?  You talk about ID, but your 3 tables include a field named 'ID'. What EXACTLY do you need ?! What are the relations between your tables ? It would help us helping you, thank you :)

Comment: The content of all 3 IDs are the same. The idea is to select an ID from the Refund form, which is in fact populated by the IDs in the Retailers table, to have Name and Status pulled from Retailers and Registration into Refund.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Refund is your base table here.  So, the query you want is:

```
SELECT a.[ID], b.[Name], c.[Status]
FROM Refund as a
Left Join Retailers as b
ON a.[ID] = b.[ID}
Left Join Registration as c
ON a.[ID] = c.[ID]
```

You'll need to make all 3 ID fields the Primary Keys in their respective tables.  This should make the query updateable, and then you can use this query as the DatSource for your form.

You also have to make sure you set up the Relationships for all the tables.  If you've never done it, it's easy to do and Microsoft gives you instructions here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-relationship-40c998dd-4875-4da4-98c8-8ac8f109b85b

By setting up referential integrity in the relationships, you can save the data.